# Como definir "charset" de uma tabela no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

No MySQL pra definir o `charset` de uma tabela podemos usar assim:

#### MySQL:

```
create table user_details (...) default character set = utf8;
```

Como posso fazer o mesmo no SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, UTF-8 é um *encoding* e não um *charset*. O *charset* a ser escolhido depende um pouco da codificação escolhida. O mesmo vale para as regras de conversão e busca do texto.

Não é possível, o SQL Server não suporta esta codificação. Coloque o texto em uma [coluna `nvarchar`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15). Se for o caso pode [especificar um `collate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) entre os disponíveis, mas nenhum deles usará a codificação UTF-8.

Se precisa do dado nesta codificação precisa fazer com que a aplicação trate para usar UTF-8 e entregar isto como deseja, mas o dado não estará gravado neste formato. Um cliente específico para o SQL Server poderia até tratar isto transparentemente, não sei se algum o faz.

Se for absolutamente necessário poderia usar o `varbinary` e fazer a codificação por conta própria, mas duvido que isto seja melhor que a conversão.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar mudar a definição da coluna para ser `NVARCHAR`. para ter 
suporte unicode.

Achei um exemplo na internet bem interessante para mostrar como pode fazer isso

### **Código:**

```
USE Test
GO

/* Create Test table with non-unicode column */
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE dbo.Test
END

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (Col1 VARCHAR(20))
GO


SELECT character_set_name,collation_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'test'

/* Change to support unicode and ensure collation */
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ALTER COLUMN col1 NVARCHAR(20) COLLATE latin1_General_CI_AS
GO

SELECT character_set_name,collation_name  FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'test'
```

**Resumindo**, você terá que converter *Column Varchar para Nvarchar*

Comment: `latin1_General_CI_AS` não é UTF-8. Nem perto disto.